# How dangerous is it to visit a website?

Tags: web-browser, http, virus

I visited theannoyingsite (not hyperlinked because it is a nightmare)

It tells you to press space for three seconds, and then it unleashes hell upon your senses. Loud noises, bouncing windows, downloading cat images forcefully onto your computer, etc. Had to restart my PC.
I doubt it's anything malicious (though can't be too sure.)

But boy was it surprising to see how much can happen just with pressing the space button (which I'm not sure was important)

So how much can a website do to somebody with standard security protocols (i.e modern browser, antivirus, etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

Browsers are the number one infection vector. Even if you have an up-to-date browser and an antivirus, there can be weaknesses that can be exploited:

- a vulnerability in the browser that has not been patched yet
- a vulnerability in a browser plug-in

So, the blanket answer is that the "worst case" is a possibility.

That's why companies are spending millions to come up with measures to protect even the modern browser from attacks.

By the way, pressing the spacebar is equivalent to clicking on something.

Comment: So should I be worried?

Comment: Should you be worried about websites that force downloads, take over your browser, and crash your machine?? Very. Should you be worried about this particular website? No. https://github.com/feross/TheAnnoyingSite.com